# Critical points of a system

Tags: differential-equations

I have the following system:

[image]

For this system I have to calculate the three equilibria (critical points).
Here are the equations in Mathematica:

```
eqH = HH'[t] == (bH/NN)*(NN - CC[t] - HH[t])*HH[t] - (sH*aH)*HH[t]
eqC = CC'[t] == (bC/NN)*(NN - CC[t] - HH[t])*CC[t] - (sC + aC)*CC[t]
eqS = SS[t] == NN - HH[t] - CC[t]
```

L have the following values for the constants:

```
NN := 400
sS := 1/5
sC := 1/7
sH := 1/5
bC := 0.45
bH := 0.4
aC := 0.1
aH := 0.1
```

But now I don't know what to do next. For critical points I don't know how to solve the equations `H'[t] == 0`, `C'[t] == 0`, `S[t] == 0`

Comment: Have you seen [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html)?

Comment: @MichaelE2 I tried to solve the system like this: `system = {eqH, eqC}` , `solSystem = DSolve[system, {hh, cc}, t]` but it's not ok

Comment: You don't want to set `S[t]==0` but you do need to set `eqH` and `eqC` equal to zero in `Solve`.  Don't use `DSolve` since you're solving algebraic equations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Block[{Nc, Sc, dC, dH, bC, bH, aC, aH, St, Ht, Ct},

 With[{$Nc = 400, $Sc = 0.2, $dC = 1./7, $dH = 0.2, $bC = 0.45, $bH = 0.4, $aC = 0.1, $aH = 0.1},
  With[{paramsRl = Thread[{Nc, Sc, dC, dH, bC, bH, aC, aH} -> {$Nc, $Sc, $dC, $dH, $bC, $bH, $aC, $aH}]},

   With[{xRHS = (bH/Nc) (Nc - Ct - Ht) Ht - (dH + aH) Ht},
    With[{yRHS = (bC/Nc) (Nc - Ct - Ht) Ct - (dC + aC) Ct},
     With[{CST = Sc - Nc + Ht + Ct},

      Block[{horIsoclRl, vertIsoclRl, critPtsRl, expr},
       (* horizontal isoclines ie dC/dH \[Equal] 0 *)
       horIsoclRl = Solve[yRHS == 0, Ct];

       (* vertical isoclines ie dC/dH \[Equal] Infintiy *)
       vertIsoclRl = Solve[xRHS == 0, Ct];

       (* critical points ie Ht' \[Equal] 0 && Ct' \[Equal] 0 *)
       critPtsRl = Solve[{xRHS == 0, yRHS == 0}, {Ht, Ct}];

       Block[{isoclGraph, critPtsGraph, cstGraph, critPtsTab, paramsTab, C, H},

        (* plot isoclines - horizontal: Gray, vertical: Blue *)
        With[{xMn = -150, xMx = 350},
         isoclGraph = MapIndexed[
           Graphics[
             If[
               #2[[1]] == 1,
               {Gray, Thin, Opacity[0.5], 
                Line[{{xMn, #1[[-1]] /. Ht -> xMn}, {xMx, #1[[-1]] /. Ht -> xMx}}]},
               {Lighter[Blue], Thin, Opacity[0.5], Line[{{xMn, #1[[-1]] /. Ht -> xMn}, {xMx, #1[[-1]] /. Ht -> xMx}}]}
               ] /. paramsRl] &,
           {{Ht, Ct} /. horIsoclRl, {Ht, Ct} /. vertIsoclRl},
           {2}
           ];

         (* plot critical points - Red *)
         critPtsGraph = Graphics[
             {PointSize[Large], Darker[Red], Point[#]}
             ] & /@ (({Ht, Ct} /. critPtsRl) /. paramsRl);

         (* plot constraint - Brown *)
         cstGraph = MapIndexed[
           Graphics[
             {Brown, Thin, Dashed, Opacity[0.7], 
               Line[{{xMn, #1[[-1]] /. Ht -> xMn}, {xMx, #1[[-1]] /. Ht -> xMx}}]} /. paramsRl] &, (({Ht, Ct} /. Solve[CST == 0, Ct]) /. paramsRl)];

         (* create critical points' table *)
         critPtsTab = Grid[

           Partition[
            Style[{Ht, Ct}, Darker[Blue]] /. critPtsRl /. paramsRl, 2,
             2, {1, 1}, {}],
           Alignment -> Left
           ];

         (* create parameters' table *)
         paramsTab = Grid[
           Prepend[
            Partition[
             Thread[

              Style[#, Gray, 12] & /@ {N, S, Subscript[δ, C], 
                 Subscript[δ, H], Subscript[β, C], Subscript[β, H], 
                 Subscript[α, C], Subscript[α, H]} -> {$Nc, $Sc, $dC, $dH, $bC, $bH, $aC, $aH}
          ], 3, 3, {1, 1}, {}], {Style["Parameters", 22], 
         SpanFromLeft}], Alignment -> Center];

         (* assemble output *)
         Labeled[
          Legended[
           Show[isoclGraph, critPtsGraph, cstGraph,
            Frame -> True,
            ImageSize -> Medium,
            FrameLabel -> {
              {Style[C, Bold, 16], None},
              {Style[H, Bold, 16], None}
              },
            RotateLabel -> False
            ],
           Column[{
             LineLegend[
              {Directive[{Gray, Thick, Opacity[0.9]}],
               Directive[{Lighter[Blue], Thick, Opacity[0.9]}],
               Directive[{Brown, Thick, Dashed, Opacity[0.9]}]
               },
              {Style["Horizontal isoclines", 18],
               Style["Vertical isoclines", 18],
               Style["Constraint (?)", 18]
               }],
             Labeled[
              PointLegend[
               {Directive[{PointSize[Large], Darker[Red]}]},
               {Style["Critical points", 18]}
               ],
              critPtsTab
              ]
            }]
           ],
          paramsTab,
          Left
          ]

         ]

        ]


       ]

      ]
     ]
    ]
   ]
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
NN = 400; sS = 1/5; sC = 1/7; sH = 1/5; bC = 0.45; bH = 0.4; aC = 0.1; aH = 0.1;

eqH = (bH/NN)*(NN - CC[t] - HH[t])*HH[t] - (sH*aH)*HH[t] == 0;

eqC = (bC/NN)*(NN - CC[t] - HH[t])*CC[t] - (sC + aC)*CC[t] == 0;

eqS = NN - HH[t] - CC[t] - SS[t] == 0

NSolve[{eqH, eqC, eqS}, {CC[t], HH[t], SS[t]}]
```